# body:before with media-query meaning in CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-position

I know how to use the `:before` selector on tag such as `p` or `span`, but how does it work on the `body` tag?

This is my CSS:

```
body {
    background: #3E3E3E;
    background: url([my-bg-img-url].jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 300;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body:before{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -10;
        background: url([my-bg-mobile-img-url].jpg) no-repeat center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Questions:

1) How does `:before` work in this case?

2) With this css code my recaptcha v2 pop up window ("select all images with...") cannot be scrolled on mobile (it is cut-off). If I remove the first `position:fixed`, even if the second one is in place, recaptcha works. Why does the first `position:fixed` create that bug on recaptcha?

3) I read that `::before` is for CSS3 and `:before` is `CSS2`, which one should I use for a compatible website?

Comment: is this live somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How does :before work in this case?

The `<body>` is unique, but it is just a HTML element, and you can have pseudo elements in it.

> 2) With this css code my recaptcha v2 pop up window ("select all images with...") cannot be scrolled on mobile (it is cut-off). If I remove the first position:fixed, even if the second one is in place, recaptcha works. Why does the first position:fixed create that bug on recaptcha?

I don't think it's caused any bugs. `position: fixed` is relative to the viewport, with `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` it covers the whole viewport completely and does not move with scrollbars.

> 3) I read that ::before is for CSS3 and :before is CSS2, which one should I use for a compatible website?

They work exactly the same, but `:before` with just one `:` works in more browsers (e.g. older version of IE).